# How to use ASCII code in keyIsDown function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to make pong in p5.js web editor to train my programmingskill a bit but i cant seem to find a way to detect ASCII key codes for payer 2`s movement, 
i provide you the code further down

is there any way to convert ASCII codes to movement? 
would be very happy if someone can provide me with it.

https://editor.p5js.org/p3nd_/sketches/rkAEBmgeV
the movement for the second player is just the duplicated movement for player one, to test things out.

This is the link to the editor and my code

Comment: Did you take a look to the examples? https://p5js.org/examples/input-keyboard.html

Comment: no but i looked through all the refrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the key code used in this block for player two (so you dont mimic P1) :

```
if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    pos1.y = pos1.y - 3;
}
//movement down for player1     
if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    pos1.y = pos1.y + 3;
}
//movement up for player2
if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    pos1.y = pos1.y - 3;
}
//movement down for player2     
if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
    pos1.y = pos1.y + 3;
}
```

The documentation tells you how here : https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyIsDown 
 and http://p5js.org/reference/#p5/keyCode

Comment: thank you very much but the first time i tried it with ASCII key code it didnt work maybe i wrote something wrong